# Maybe Int expression using unique data type

Tags: haskell

I'm wrote a unique data type to express basic math (addition, mult, etc.) and it works - however, when I try to turn it into a Maybe statement, none of the math works. I believe it's a syntax error but I've tried extra parenthesis and so on and I can't figure it out. Usually Maybe statements are easy but I don't understand why it keeps throwing an issue.

This is the data type I created (with examples):

```
data Math = Val Int
           | Add Math Math
           | Sub Math Math
           | Mult Math Math
           | Div Math Math
    deriving Show

ex1 :: Math
ex1 = Add1 (Val1 2) (Val1 3)

ex2 :: Math
ex2 = Mult (Val 2) (Val 3)

ex3 :: Math
ex3 = Div (Val 3) (Val 0)
```

Here is the code. The only Nothing return should be a division by zero.

```
expression :: Math -> Maybe Int
expression (Val n)        = Just n
expression (Add e1 e2)    = Just (expression e1) + (expression e2)
expression (Sub e1 e2)    = Just (expression e1) - (expression e2)
expression (Mult e1 e2)   = Just (expression e1) * (expression e2)
expression (Div e1 e2)
  | e2 /= 0               = Just (expression e1) `div` (expression e2)
  | otherwise             = Nothing
```

I get the same error for every individual mathematical equation, even if I delete the others, so I'm certain it's syntax. The error makes it seem like a Maybe within a Maybe but when I do that `e1 /= 0 && e2 /= 0 = Just (Just (expression e1)`div`(expression e2))`, I get the same error:

```
 * Couldn't match type `Int' with `Maybe Int'
    Expected type: Maybe (Maybe Int)
      Actual type: Maybe Int
 * In the second argument of `div', namely `(expression e2)'
    In the expression: Just (expression e1) `div` (expression e2)
    In an equation for `expression':
      expression (Div e1 e2)
        | e1 /= 0 && e2 /= 0 = Just (expression e1) `div` (expression e2)
        | otherwise = Nothing
   |
56 |   | e1 /= 0 && e2 /= 0 = Just (expression e1) `div` (expression e2)
   |                                        ^^^^^^^^^
```

What am I missing? It's driving me crazy.

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to call the `expression` function recursively, but it doesn't have the right return type - `Just (expression e1)` actually has type `Maybe (Maybe Int)`, because `expression` returns a `Maybe Int`.

Comment: Although you do have precedence issues too: `Just (expression e1) + (expression e2)` is parsed as `(Just (expression e1)) + (expression e2)` which I'm assuming is not how you meant it.

Comment: The second issue is just a typo, I think. It isn't in my code. For the first, how would I recursively call a Maybe (Maybe Int)? Do use some form of `Just (Maybe expression e1)` or `Maybe (Just expression e1)`. I've been toying with the syntax and can't get it to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the first issue is precedence. Instead of writing:

```hs
Just (expression e1) * (expression e2)
```

You probably want:

```hs
Just (expression e1 * expression e2)
```

The second issue is the *types*. Take a look at the type of (*), for instance:

```hs
>>> :t (*)
(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

It says, for some type `a` that is a `Num`, it takes two `a`s and returns one `a`. Specialised to `Int`, that would be:

```hs
(*) :: Int -> Int -> Int
```

But `expression` returns a `Maybe Int`! So we need some way to multiply with `Maybe`s. Let's write the function ourselves:

```hs
multMaybes :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
multMaybes Nothing _ = Nothing
multMaybes _ Nothing = Nothing
multMaybes (Just x) (Just y) = Just (x * y)
```

So if either side of the multiplication has failed (i.e. you found a divide-by-zero), the whole thing will fail. Now, we need to do this once for every operator:

```hs
addMaybes Nothing _ = Nothing
addMaybes _ Nothing = Nothing
addMaybes (Just x) (Just y) = Just (x + y)

subMaybes Nothing _ = Nothing
subMaybes _ Nothing = Nothing
subMaybes (Just x) (Just y) = Just (x - y)
```

And so on. But we can see there's a lot of repetition here. Luckily, there's a function that does this pattern already: `liftA2`.

```hs
multMaybes = liftA2 (*)
addMaybes  = liftA2 (+)
subMaybes  = liftA2 (-)
```

Finally, there are two more small problems. First, you say:

```hs
expression (Div e1 e2)
  | e2 /= 0               = Just (expression e1) `div` (expression e2)
```

But `e2` isn't an `Int`! It's the expression type. You probably want to check if the result of the recursive call is 0.

The second problem is that you're unnecessarily wrapping things in `Just`: we can remove one layer.

After all of that, we can write your function like this:

```hs
expression :: Math -> Maybe Int
expression (Val n)        = Just n
expression (Add e1 e2)    = liftA2 (+) (expression e1) (expression e2)
expression (Sub e1 e2)    = liftA2 (-) (expression e1) (expression e2)
expression (Mult e1 e2)   = liftA2 (*) (expression e1) (expression e2)
expression (Div e1 e2)
  | r2 /= Just 0          = liftA2 div (expression e1) r2
  | otherwise             = Nothing
  where r2 = expression e2
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems here:

```
 Just (expression e1)  + (expression e2)
```

is interpreted as:

```
(Just (expression e1)) + (expression e2)
```

So that means that you have wrapped the left value in a `Just`, whereas the other one is not, and this will not make much sense.

Secondly, both `expression e1` and `expression e2` have type `Maybe Int`, hence that means that you can not add these two together. We can perform pattern matching.

Fortunately there is a more elegant solution: we can make use of [**`liftM2 :: Monad m => (a -> b -> c) -> m a -> m b -> m c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:liftM2) for *most* of the patterns. For `Maybe` the `liftM2` will take a function `f :: a -> b -> c` and two `Maybe`s, and if both are `Just`s it will call the function on the values that are wrapped in the `Just`s and then wrap the result in a `Just` as well.

As for the division case, we will first have to obtain the result of the denominator with the `expression` function, and if that is a `Just` that is *not* equal to zero, then we can [**`fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fmap) function to map a value in a `Just` (that of the numerator) given of course the numerator is a `Just`:

```
import Control.Monad(liftM2)

expression :: Math -> Maybe Int
expression (Val n)  = Just n
expression (Add e1 e2) = liftM2 (+) (expression e1) (expression e2)
expression (Sub e1 e2) = liftM2 (-) (expression e1) (expression e2)
expression (Mult e1 e2) = liftM2 (*) (expression e1) (expression e2)
expression (Div e1 e2) | Just v2 <- expression e2, v2 /= 0 = fmap (`div` v2) (expression e1)
                       | otherwise = Nothing
```

or we can, like @RobinZigmond says, use [**`(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--36--62-) and [**`(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a ->  f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--42--62-):

```
expression :: Math -> Maybe Int
expression (Val n)  = Just n
expression (Add e1 e2) = (+) <$> expression e1 <*> expression e2
expression (Sub e1 e2) = (-) <$> expression e1 <*> expression e2
expression (Mult e1 e2) = (*) <$> expression e1 <*> expression e2
expression (Div e1 e2) | Just v2 &lt;- expression e2, v2 /= 0 = (`div` v2) <$> expression e1
                       | otherwise = Nothing
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without library functions? I'm trying to show the operation so elegance isn't really an issue.

Comment: @Francis: sure, `liftM2` iss nothing special, basically it just uses pattern matching to see if the two parameters are `Just`s and then unwrap the value, pass it through a function, and wrap it in a `Just`, if the two are not both `Just`s, then it returns `Nothing`, so you can implement this quite straightforward.

Comment: note that you can use `liftA2` instead of `liftM2` (it's the same function, but `liftA2` works for more types - they both work here since `Maybe` is a monad but I prefer to do eg. `liftA2 (+) (expression e1) (expression e2)`, or even `(+) <$> expression e1 <*> expression e2`, just because I don't see the point of using Monad-specific functions if you don't actually need them.